# Trigger Slider on Button click with Slick Slide Not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, slick.js

I have been trying to make a slider that has custom buttons using the Slick Slide library. When you trigger the "#slider-swap" the slide should change to the second slide which has the same button (different name) that swaps the slide back to the first.

I did make my own flipbox but ended up sticking with this as it will do the job without loading any additional JS.

However when I trigger the button, nothing happens. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a feeling its something with the HTML markup and slick is getting confused to what to flick between.

Any ideas? It might because it's quite late and I have been working on this project since 8am :X

```
<div class="cs-challenge">
<div class="front"> 
    <div class="cs-heading chalbg">
        <i class="fal fa-bullseye"></i>
        <h3>The Challenge</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="cs-content solbg chaltxt">
        <ul>
            <li>An uneven fouling covered at least 70% of the convection bank finned 
            surface.</li>
            <li>Deposit was airborne hydro carbon dust and refractory fines – packed tightly
            between all rows of convection side fined heater tubes</li>
            <li>Severely restricted access to the convection section.</li>
            <li>To clean the tube side using studded pigging at the same time.</li>
        </ul>
        <a class="btn" id="slider-swap" href="#">Change Slide</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="back">
    <div class="cs-heading solbg">
        <i class="fal fa-bullseye-arrow"></i>
        <h3>Solution</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="cs-content chalbg soltxt">
        <ul>
            <li>An uneven fouling covered at least 70% of the convection bank finned 
            surface.</li>
            <li>Deposit was airborne hydro carbon dust and refractory fines – packed tightly
            between all rows of convection side fined heater tubes</li>
            <li>Severely restricted access to the convection section.</li>
            <li>To clean the tube side using studded pigging at the same time.</li>
        </ul>
        <a class="btn" id="slider-swap" href="#">Change Slide</a>
    </div>
</div> 
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".cs-challenge").slick({
          autoplay: false,
          speed: 250,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          fade: true,
          arrows: false,
          cssEase: 'linear',
          infinite: true
        });

    });
    var indexVal=1;
    $("#slider-swap").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $( ".cs-challenge" ).slickGoTo(indexVal);
            indexVal=indexVal+1;
            if(indexVal>2){
            indexVal=1;
            }
        });
</script>
```

Here is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/no30vq8h/

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it.

So for one, .slickGoTo is depreciated function, no longer works (afaik?). I have changed it to use indexVal with .data('id'); and html data-id attributes for the button.

Now when you trigger the button, it will go between each slide.

```
<a class="btn slider-swap" data-id="2" href="#">Challenge</a>

    //var indexVal=1;
jQuery(".slider-swap").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var indexVal = jQuery(this).data('id');
        console.log(indexVal);
        jQuery( ".cs-challenge" ).slick('slickGoTo',indexVal);
        /*indexVal=indexVal+1;
        if(indexVal>2){
        indexVal=1;
        }*/

    });
```

Here is the final code.
https://pastebin.com/fH68Uw8W

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the UI in the shared jsfiddle link. The slider is not applying to which it is applied. Please add slick js CDN.

You can use **slickGoTo** like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".cs-challenge").slick({
  autoplay: false,
  speed: 250,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  fade: true,
  arrows: false,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  infinite: true
});
var indexVal=1;
$("#slider-swap").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $( ".cs-challenge" ).slick('slickGoTo',indexVal);
    indexVal=indexVal+1;
    if(indexVal>2){
    indexVal=1;
    }
});
```

});